# How can I fix an Axios interceptor causing property 'status' of undefined error

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a selection to set permissions for elements to global or private. I'm using the Axios interceptor request to handle looking for the permissions field to have data and, if it does, stringify it. The problem is, it causes me to get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined" when I attempt to reload the program at all. The only "fix" right now is to log out, remove the interceptor, log in, read it, and then run the check again.

Because of this, I can't even get to the home dashboard of the software. If I clear my cookies, I can go back to the login screen, but no further than that after attempting to log in.

Is there something I'm missing for it? below is the interceptor code. If more information or context is needed, please let me know.

```
export default {
  install: (Vue) => {
    Vue.$eventBus = new Vue();

    Vue.axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
      return response.data;
    }, async error => {
      if (error.response.status === 401 && error.config.url != '/api/authentication/login') {
        var config = await Vue.$configService.find();
        window.location = config.accountPortalUrl;
        return
      }      
      console.log(error);
      Vue.$eventBus.$emit('notifyUser', 'Uh oh, something went wrong!');
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    Vue.axios.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        // check request method -> use post if many params
        if (config.data.permissions) {
          config.data.permissions = JSON.stringify(config.data.permissions);
        }
        console.log(config);
        return config;
       
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer ultimately was something extremely simple.

```
if (config.data.permissions)
```

needed to be

```
if (config.data && config.data.permissions)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your service API is not responding, this might happen if the user is not authenticated . Your error is at line where you check (error.response.status).  Its only possible to get an undefined response when the request was interrupted before response. Most probably if you check your browser network pannel you will see that the preflight check for this request causes a 401 network error. Hence because the preflight failed your actual response comes as undefined. You should sanity check first if your server responded with a response or not and then access the response status.

Something like this might help

```
if (error.response) {
  // Request was made and the server responded successfully
  // You can now de-structure the response object to get the status
  console.log(error.response.status);
} else if (error.request) {
   //  request was made but not responded by server
   console.log(error.request);
}
```

Comment: It's weird, because I'm authenticated fine if I don't do the permissions check. It's only when I have that in that it errors out and doesn't load whatsoever

Comment: Did you check the network logs ? Any 401 errors or preflight failures ?

Comment: Nothing shows it the network. It doesn't even get that far when loading